# android option menu crashes

Tags: android, menu

I have a question about the menu in android.

I´ve created a About.class + about.xml. In the MainActivity.java I pasted the following code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(my_options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.about:
                intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

When I click on the menu, the 2 points "About" and "Help" appears. But when I click on one of these entries, the app crashes. what do I have to do, that the about.xml will open when I click on "About" in the menu ?

Comment: "I´ve created a About.class" that doesn't sound right..

Comment: Where is your About.class.

Comment: Post the crash log. There is a probability of getting a crash due to problems in the About activity.

Comment: mhh, I am new. I am not sure, if the `About.class` isn't right:

'import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class About extends Activity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.about);

    }

}'

Comment: Can someone look at my `About.class` ? Is there a mistake inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

In `my_options_menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  
    <item  android:id="@+id/item1"  
        android:title="About"/>  
    <item  android:id="@+id/item2"  
        android:title="Help"/>  
</menu>
```

In MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
    }  
    @Override  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_options_menu, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu  
        return true;  
    }  
    @Override  
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
        switch (item.getItemId()) {  
            case R.id.item1:  
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;     
           case R.id.item2:  
               Intent intent = new Intent(this, Help.class);
            startActivity(intent);
              return true;     

              default:  
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

About.class

```
public class About extends Activity {   
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);

    } 
}
```

And dont forget to add a text or background color to about.xml

Comment: mhh, I am new. I am not sure, if the About.class isn't right:

`import android.app.Activity;import android.os.Bundle;  
public class About extends Activity { @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.about); } }`

Comment: About.class is your About.java activity

Comment: THX. works fine. And may not forget to insert the 2 new activities in the `AndroidManifest.xml`